# Get-Childitem not working in directories with accentuation

Tags: powershell, acl, get-childitem

I am try to get some ntfs permissions from directories using Get-ChildItem, but they do not seem to work when these directories contains accentuation. Unfortunately I am not allowed to rename the directory.

In the codes I have, lets pretend we have a directory named \server\folder1\óóó\company1 and I must get some information from it.

When I try to run the script, a blank csv file is generated.

I have tried to make it work in 3 scripts, such as below.

```
$FolderPath = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\server\folder1\óóó\company1" -Recurse -Depth 3 -Directory -Force
$Report = @()
Foreach ($Folder in $FolderPath) {
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $Folder.FullName
    foreach ($Access in $acl.Access)
        {
            $Properties = [ordered]@{'FolderName'=$Folder.FullName;'AD
Group or
User'=$Access.IdentityReference;'Permissions'=$Access.FileSystemRights;'Inherited'=$Access.IsInherited}
            $Report += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $Properties
        }
}
$Report | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\FolderPermissions.csv" -Encoding Default -Delimiter ";"
```

```
$path = "\\server\folder1\óóó\company1" #define path to the shared folder
$reportpath ="$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\FolderPermissions.csv" #define path to export permissions report
Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Depth 3 -Directory -Force | where { $_.PsIsContainer } | % { $path1 = $_.fullname; Get-Acl $_.Fullname | % { $_.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path1 -passthru }} | Export-Csv $reportpath -Encoding Default -Delimiter ";"
```

```
$path = "\\server\folder1\óóó\company1"
$shares = Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -Depth 3 -Directory -Force | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer }
$data = foreach($share in $shares){
    $path = $share.Name
    $acls = Get-Acl $share.Fullname
    foreach($acl in $acls){
        $acl.access | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty '.\Application Data' -Value $path -passthru
    }
}
$data | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\FolderPermissions.csv" -Encoding Default -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: What happens if you try `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` and the path with single quotes (`'`)?

Comment: Hello, ive edited the three scripts and the same still happens, blank csv output file.